# How to combine multiple DATA-SET commands in SAS like we have different queries in SQL combined via UNION

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

My question is How to combine multiple DATA-SET commands in SAS like we have different queries in SQL combined via UNION.

I have to create two data sets in work library using the a condition.

```
    data new_car_sales2;
    set mylib1.car_sales;
    where (15<price_in_thousands <20) and price_in_thousands NE .;
    run;
    data new_car_sales3;
    set mylib1.car_sales;
    where (20<price_in_thousands <25) and price_in_thousands NE .;
    run;
```

now I can run by selecting both the code at the same time and is creating two different data-set in work library. but is there any keyword i can use like UNION in sql to add these two code blocks.

Thanks!!

Comment: Do you want one data set in the output or two?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is confusing since the code example is creating multiple output datasets from one input, but in the text you talk about SQL UNION which would be used to create a single output dataset from multiple input datasets.

You can reference multiple output datasets on the DATA statement and then specify which one you want to write on the OUTPUT statement.

```
data new_car_sales2 new_car_sales3;
  set mylib1.car_sales;
  if (15<price_in_thousands <20) then output new_car_sales2;
  if (20<price_in_thousands <25) then output new_car_sales3;
run;
```

I notice that your conditions exclude the case when the value is exactly 20.  Note that if you use an OUTPUT statement without any target datasets then the record is written to all of them.  So you might add this statement to write the 20s to both sets.

```
  if 20 = price_in_thousands then output;
```

Comment: This is working as I expected and as I was looking for. using DATA and SET only once and creating more than one dataset in same library.
Thanks!!

Comment: @user2827927 If you wanted what Tom is showing here, you asked for it entirely backwards.  `UNION` *combines* two datasets.  The above *splits* a dataset into two.  Please edit your question to reflect what you actually want.

Answer (score 0):

You can just put them both on the same SET statement, and put the `where` in the `set` statement.

```
  data new_car_sales2;
    set mylib1.car_sales(where=( (15<price_in_thousands <20) and price_in_thousands NE .)) 
        mylib1.car_sales(where=((20<price_in_thousands <25) and price_in_thousands NE .);
  run;
```

This is slightly different from what you'd get if you combined the WHERE conditions.

```
  data new_car_sales2;
    set mylib1.car_sales;
    where ((15<price_in_thousands <20) and price_in_thousands NE .)) 
       or ((20<price_in_thousands <25) and price_in_thousands NE .);
  run;
```

That's because the first will take the first SET and then take the second SET dataset.  The second will take rows from either one in the order it finds them.

Note both of these exclude `price_in_thousands=20` since they both use exclusive GT/LT rather than GE/LE (`<=` `>=`).

Comment: Note: this answers what the question appears to ask (how to do the same thing as `UNION` in SAS), but comments seem to indicate it does not answer what the original poster *meant* to ask (the inverse, how does one create multiple tables in one data step).  If the question is updated I'll be removing this.